# Scheduling tasks in iOS - where do i start?

Tags: ios, notifications, scheduled-tasks

In my app i want to fire a notification after exact time, where i mean days rather than seconds. I need to accomplish that event without using a server side - whole app must be running on the device itself.

So there is my question - is there any class that would let me do that, and will remember tasks even if a user kills the app, or switches his phone off and on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Local notifications.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194